# Adding hyperlinks to other sections of the README file

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

How do I add links on readme.md file on GitHub to other sections of my readme.md file (such as the different headings and such)?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should try this:

```
[Section Name](readme.md#Section)
```

Let me know if it works